Que metodo de SQLite puedo usar para una consulta anidada donde una depende del resultado de la otra?
Tengo un proyecto con Express.js y sqlite donde tengo un endpoint que primero realiza un insert a una tabla y dependiendo del resultado obtiene el id de la fila que inserto para usarlo en un insert en otra tabla. El endpoint es este:
app.post("/api/registrarCompra", (req, res) => {
  const { date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId, products } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  db.run(
    `INSERT INTO facturas(date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId) VALUES(${date}, ${paymentMethod}, ${employeId}, ${clientId})`,
    (err, factura) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send("error del servidor");
      } else {
        try {
          products.forEach((item) => {
            db.run(
              `INSERT INTO productosFacturas(facturaId, productoId, quantity) VALUES(${factura}, ${item.id}, ${item.quantity})`
            );
          });
          res.status(200).send("factura realizada con exito");
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send("error del servidor");
        }
      }
    }
  );
});

Pero cada vez que intento usarlo la api se cierra por error, al parecer el id del primer insert retorna undefined por lo que estuve leyendo el método db.run() no retorna los datos pero tampoco se que método puedo utilizar aquí.

Me gusta más utilizar MySQL porque se me hace más fácil o porque ya me acostumbre, pero si no mal recuerdo con SQLite para acceder al id del .run() es con this:
this.lastID devolvía el ultimo ID que se inserto.
Así que si necesitas utilizar el ID seria algo como esto:
db.run(`INSERT INTO facturas(date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`, [date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId], function(err) {
if(err){
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send('error en el primer')
}
const id = this.lastID;
console.log(id);
});

Y ya después agregas el forEach despues de guardar el ID:
db.run(`INSERT INTO facturas(date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`, [date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId], function(err) {
if(err){
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send('error en el primer')
}
const id = this.lastID;
products.forEach(item => {
    db.run(`INSERT INTO productosFacturas(facturaId, productoId, quantity) VALUES(?, ?, ?)`, [id, item.id, item.quantity])
});
});

También te recomendaría separar la query del insert de los datos que vas a guardar, así como lo puse anteriormente, con los signos de interrogación en los valores para indicar donde se van a colocar los datos y después los datos como un array en el orden correspondiente, es decir, el primer signo de interrogación es el valor del primer dato en el array.
Una disculpa si estoy omitiendo algo.

ya lo intente tal cual pero this.lastID tambien esta retornando undefined. –

@JesusDavidLozano la tabla que estas manejando tiene la columna de id como autoincrementable?, porque usar this.lastID solo tiene sentido si en la tabla la llave primaria "id" es autoincrementable, yo nomas supuse que la tabla ya es así pero no lo especifique en mi respuesta

si, es autoincrementable, por eso no le paso valor de id. al final opte por usar un generador de UIDs.

Tienes que usar db.run()con una función de callback para acceder al ID. Queda así:
app.post("/api/registrarCompra", (req, res) => {
  const { date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId, products } = req.body;
  db.run(
    `INSERT INTO facturas(date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`,
    [date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId],
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send("Error del servidor");
      } else {
        const facturaId = this.lastID;
        try {
          const insertProduct = db.prepare(
            `INSERT INTO productosFacturas(facturaId, productoId, quantity) VALUES(?, ?, ?)`
          );
          products.forEach((item) => {
            insertProduct.run(facturaId, item.id, item.quantity, (err) => {
              if (err) {
                throw err;
              }
            });
          });
          insertProduct.finalize();
          res.status(200).send("Factura realizada con éxito");
        } catch (err) {
          res.status(500).send("Error del servidor");
        }
      }
    }
  );
});

En el INSERT usamos ? para evitar inyecciones SQL. this.lastId obtiene el ID de la fila insertada, para la segunda inserción utilizamos db.prepare() y ejecutamos.
Pero esto sigue sin ser lo optimo, ya que para hacer lo que quieres hacer tendrías que emplear una transacción, ejemplo:
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Insertar en tabla facturas
INSERT INTO facturas(date, paymentMethod, employeId, clientId) VALUES('2024-09-10', 'credit_card', 1, 1);

-- Obtener ID
SELECT last_insert_rowid() INTO @facturaId;

-- Insertar en tabla productosFacturas
INSERT INTO productosFacturas(facturaId, productoId, quantity) VALUES(@facturaId, 101, 2);
INSERT INTO productosFacturas(facturaId, productoId, quantity) VALUES(@facturaId, 102, 3);
INSERT INTO productosFacturas(facturaId, productoId, quantity) VALUES(@facturaId, 103, 1);

COMMIT;

Donde utilizas SELECT last_insert_rowid() INTO @facturaId; para obtener el ID de la última fila insertada almacenándolo después en la variable @facturaId. En esta pregunta puedes ver un ejemplo de como implementarlo con Express.
Documentación
database.prepare(sql)
Transaction

ya lo intente tal cual pero this.lastID tambien esta retornando undefined.

Deberías de mencionar que librería estas utilizando.
